# Strange problem of inconsistent numpy and pypy versions

Tags: pypy

Before：
pypy：pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64.tar.bz2
numpy：1.22.3
numpy works fine in the environment

Now：
pypy：pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64.tar.bz2
numpy：1.22.3
numpy does not work in the environment

error message

````
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/usr/local/pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/usr/local/pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
ImportError: /usr/local/pypy3.9-v7.3.9-linux64/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.pypy39-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyInterpreterState_GetID```



Did not find any changes in people pypy and numpy. I do not know what the real reason is?
````